# Jquery Find ID and append to input

Tags: html, jquery

I have the following html. I'd like to find the ID on span class="form-error" and include the ID to the aria-describedby on the input

```
    <label class="Name cell medium-6  ">
<span class="field-title">Name*</span>
<div class="searchbar search-form search-tradein">                        
    <searchbox use-suggest="true" hide-suggest-onblur="true" suggest-onfocus="true">                            
        <input id="searchbox2" onclick="searchFocus();" name="122" data-elementid="122" class="related-data-element" data-elementtype="Answer" required="" aria-describedby="">                        
    </searchbox>                                      
</div>
<span class="form-error" id="z6an3x-abide-error" role="alert">Please add Name</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Or, more likely what you meant ...   `$('#searchbox2').attr("aria-describedby",$(".form-error").attr("id"))`

Comment: (original comment was removed due to small typo which the above corrected)